# CakePHP 4 Forms: do not preselect on multiple select

Tags: cakephp

Here's the situation: I have a multi-staged tunnel that basically passes a user from page to page via form submits. Fill out stage one, click submit, get sent to page two and soforth. The trouble is that my fields are creating similarly-named form elements, so when the new page loads, Cake seems to see it as the same form as the previous one. Thus, the checkboxes selected in the first form get checked in the second form, even though they are of completely different values.

TL;DR is there a way to specify with this call that there should absolutely NOT be any prefilling of the fields?

```php
<?= $this->Form->control('estimate_options.0.option_value', [
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $deliverables,
    'label' => false,
    'value' => !empty($selectedDeliverables->option_value) ? $selectedDeliverables->option_value : false,
]);
?>
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to pass "false" (I've also tried NULL) as the 'value' to specify that nothing should be selected, but they get checked anyway?

Comment: You have a field called `estimate_options.0.option_value` on different pages of the form? Are you saving the data as you go along, or collecting it all to save at once at the end?

Comment: Ok, I guess I solved my own problem by just changing the index number. Thanks!